# Find Same Values Between 2 ArrayList And Return As Another ArrayList

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist, ienumerable

I am trying to **extract the values shared by two arraylist into another arraylist.**

```
using System.Linq;

private ArrayList GetSameOf2AL(ArrayList first, ArrayList second)
        {
            ArrayList same = new ArrayList();

            var one = from int i in first select i;
            var two = from int i in second select i;

            var SameVal = one.Intersect(two);
            //I am supposed to convert or cast SameVal into arraylist here
            return same;
        }
```

My questions are:

1. I couldn't convert the `var` type back into `arraylist`, can someone advise me how?
2. Did I choose a wrong method to do this at the first place? Your advise is appreciated.

Thank you all for your kind attention =)

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` in the first place? There is no reason for this, use `List<T>`

Comment: @BrokenGlass I am dealing with legacy code...

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this is legacy code if you're able to use LINQ... :)

Comment: No... the parameters were passed from the legacy code (arraylist first & second).. I am creating new method to deal with the parameters.. And return back sth that can be processed back by those legacy codes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<int> intersection = first.Cast<int>().Intersect(second.Cast<int>()).ToList();
```

or

```
ArrayList intersection = new ArrayList();
foreach (var i in first.Cast<int>().Intersect(second.Cast<int>()))
    intersection.Add(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, ArrayList is an outdated collection that was used before Generics was introduced to .NET. You should not use it unless you're building legacy code. Instead you should turn your attention towards the List class.

```
IEnumerable<int> first = new []{1,2,3};
IEnumerable<int> second = new [] {2,3,4};

List<int> intersection = first.Intersect(second).ToList(); // result {2,3}
```

If you are in legacy mode then generics won't be available to you, and you will have to manually iterate the lists to find the intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are dealing with legacy code you can just use a simple `foreach` loop:

```
private ArrayList GetSameOf2AL(ArrayList first, ArrayList second)
{
    ArrayList same = new ArrayList();

    var one = from int i in first select i;
    var two = from int i in second select i;

    var sameVal = one.Intersect(two);
    //I am supposed to convert or cast SameVal into arraylist here
    foreach (int i in sameVal)
        same.Add(i);
    return same;
}
```

This is really patchwork though, it would be much preferable to refactor your code to use `List<int>` instead of `ArrayList` - the effort shouldn't be too much and it will pay off immediately.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `ToList` and `AddRange` (or maybe not `ToList` at all)?

Comment: @M.Babcock That would be another option- though it's the same under the hood and you are creating a "throw away" collection (not that it matters I guess)

Answer (score 1):

This is a time when using the `var` keyword as a shortcut to explicitly writing out the type can run you into trouble. If you had checked the return of the `Intersect` LINQ extension, you'd see that the return is an `IEnumerable<int>`. You can use some of the `IEnumerable` extension methods to transfer the data represented by the `IEnumerable` to an `ArrayList`:

```
private ArrayList GetSameOf2AL(ArrayList first, ArrayList second)
{
    ArrayList same = new ArrayList();

    var one = from int i in first select i;
    var two = from int i in second select i;

    same.AddRange(one.Intersect(two).ToArray<int>());
    return same;
}
```