# An intersect for 2 Arraylists

Tags: c#

I've got 2 `ArrayList`s and i want to find common elements from those 2.

Example:

`Arraylist 1` contains: `"Cat"`, `"Dog"`, `"Phone"`, `"Watch"`, `"Monkey".`

`Arraylist 2` contains: `"Dog"`, `"Phone"`, `"Chair".`

As a result i want to have a method which returns : `"Dog"` and `"Phone"`.

I've used an `Array` before and the intersect worked with the `Array`, but I'm using an `ArrayList` now.

Comment: Why don't you use array if it works for you? And why you want to use ArrayList? Have you tried something so far? Have you tired a search option(BTW found results immediately when googled your question title)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Same Values Between 2 ArrayList And Return As Another ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900181/find-same-values-between-2-arraylist-and-return-as-another-arraylist)

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore, there is no reason. Use a generic `List<T>`, in this case a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList{ "cat", "dog" ,"phone", "watch"};
ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList{ "pen", "cat", "dog", "lamp" };

var elements = Enumerable.Intersect(list1.ToArray(), list2.ToArray()).ToArray();
ArrayList result = new ArrayList(elements);
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
        ArrayList first = new ArrayList();
        first.Add("Cat");
        first.Add("Dog");

        ArrayList second = new ArrayList();
        second.Add("Dog");
        second.Add("Phone");

        ArrayList final = new ArrayList();
        foreach (var i in first.Cast<string>().Intersect(second.Cast<string>()))
            final.Add(i);
```

The resulting ArrayList is `Dog`

Answer (score 0):

I would implement an extension method for `Intersect`, so you can use it just as you would for any other iterable collection:

```
public static class ArrayListExtensions
{
    public static ArrayList Intersect(this ArrayList source, ArrayList other)
        => new ArrayList(source.ToArray().Intersect(other.ToArray()).ToArray());
}
```

Usage:

```
var first = new ArrayList(new[] { "Cat", "Dog", "Phone", "Watch", "Monkey" });
var second = new ArrayList(new[] { "Dog", "Phone", "Chair" });

var intersection = first.Intersect(second); // intersection is now an ArrayList
```